# How to account for quantity of items in a ratio formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to find a ratio-like formula that takes into account the difference between the number of items in stock and those that are on sale, as well as the actual number of items in stock and on sale.

The difference between 2 and 1 is not important and throws off the reports. 
The difference between 20,000 and 10,000 is way more important. 
However, The different between 2000 and 10 though is even more important.

Just a simple ratio would usually work but not in this case since the actual quantity of items (or those on sale) are not accounted for...I get a .4 ratio when only 5 items are in stock (Item 9 below).

I looked at using the percentage difference first but it wouldn't work even if the amount of items in stock are taken into account being that numbers can be identical (items 12 & 13 below).

Let me know if I need to clarify.

```
    +-----------+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+
| Item Name | In stock  | On Sale | Ratio  | Perc Diff |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+
| Item 12   | 1         |       1 | 1.0000 | 0.0000    |
| Item 13   | 1         |       1 | 1.0000 | 0.0000    |
| Item 1    | 1,000     |     500 | 0.5000 | -0.5000   |
| Item 2    | 900       |     400 | 0.4444 | -0.5556   |
| Item 9    | 5         |       2 | 0.4000 | -0.6000   |
| Item 3    | 800       |     300 | 0.3750 | -0.6250   |
| Item 8    | 300       |     100 | 0.3333 | -0.6667   |
| Item 11   | 3         |       1 | 0.3333 | -0.6667   |
| Item 4    | 700       |     200 | 0.2857 | -0.7143   |
| Item 7    | 400       |     100 | 0.2500 | -0.7500   |
| Item 10   | 4         |       1 | 0.2500 | -0.7500   |
| Item 6    | 500       |     100 | 0.2000 | -0.8000   |
| Item 5    | 600       |     100 | 0.1667 | -0.8333   |
+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Can you not just use the inverse of your ratio 1/ratio, which will assign a greater weight to bigger percentage disparities or are you after something else...and example of what you want to achieve would be nice.

Comment: Nah that doesn't work either. For example Item 10 in the table above would rank #4 with only 4 items in stock and 1 on sale.

Comment: Have to tried weighting the delta? I just played with the data and did an absolute difference column, percentage difference column, and then the absolute difference raised to the power of the percentage (if formula to only apply on any difference). Looks ok, will have to think more about the relationships though, its a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a weight of the percentage difference against the absolute or instock value should improve your results, I needed to add an image to explain what I was doing properly.

[image: Example of weighted difference.]